# How to redirect the output of a program to the Linux diff command

Tags: linux, redirection, pipe

I have a program that writes to [stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29). Is there a way that I can redirect the output to the Linux [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) command or do I have to write the output to a file and then compare that?

For example, I have a bunch of test input files for a program and the corresponding expected output in another set of files. And I'd like to do something like `./program < t1.input | diff t1.expected`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
./program < t1.input | diff t1.expected -
```

Answer (score 5):

In bash:

```
diff t1.expected <(./program < t1.input)
```

Comment: Do you know of anyway to do that straight from a linux command line? When I try what you posted I get "Missing name for redirection."

Comment: Stop putting extra spaces.

Comment: What do you mean by extra spaces?

Comment: You have a space between the `<` and the `(`. Don't do that.

Answer (score 4):

Or the simple way using bash:

```
diff <(./program) <(cat t1.expected)
```

I often use the more general case

```
diff <(command1) <(command2)
```

where the two commands might be similar except for e.g. different input files, or different versions of a program operating on the same file. Also works with gvimdiff.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to diff two outputs of programs, zsh is your friend:

```
$ diff =(program1 < input1) =(program2 < input2)
```